# Yii2 url manager don't parse urls with get parameter

Tags: php, url-rewriting, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-url-manager

I've created a module named catalogue with, for the moment, two actions in the default controller:

1. actionIndex
2. actionLineProducts

in the index view I have some link which run the line-product's action, the url was the result of:

```
Url::to(['line-products', 'line' => $line->name])
```

my goal is to obtain a link like

> catalogue/{line-name}

where line-name is the parameter I send to action LineProducts.
My urlManager configurations are:

```
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
'showScriptName' => false,
'rules' => [
      '<moduls:catalogue>/<controller:default>/<action:line-products>/<line:*>' => '<module>/<line>',
      '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view/',
      '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
      '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
 ],
```

.htaccess configurations:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Can anyone explain me why my URL is always like:

> http://my-site.dev/catalogue/default/line-products?line={line-name}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You swapped the configuration. The key is the pattern of the url as passed from the browser. The value is the route. Since you are using a specific module, controller and action you can pass those in directly:

```
'rules' => [
    'catalogue/<line>' => 'catalogue/default/line-products'
    ...
]
```

You can read the [Routing and Url Creation page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules) in the Yii2 guide for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I put  the rule on my  urlManager config but this catch an exception: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 25