# YII 2 Url Route not working with $_GET parameters

Tags: php, yii2

I'm new to Yii2 and their URL ruling is kinda tricky. I have a `SiteController` with an action like this

```
public function actionSuccessStories($slug = null)
{
    // some codes
}
```

in my config i have this

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'rules' => [
        // Default routes
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

        // page routes
        'success-stories/<slug:\w+>' => 'site/success-stories',

        // Remove 'site' parameter from URL
        '<action:(.*)>' => 'site/<action>',
    ],
],
```

in my view i have this to generate my url

```
Url::to(['site/success-stories', 'slug' => 'slug_value'], true);
```

my problem is `Url::to();` creates `success-stories?slug=slug_value`

instead of

`success-stories/slug/slug_value` am i doing this right? What i want to accomplish is the second format.

I've read this question related to mine but it covers only modules
[Yii2 url manager don't parse urls with get parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836863/yii2-url-manager-dont-parse-urls-with-get-parameter)

Comment: Youre missing `-` sign, try: `'success-stories/<slug:\w+>' => 'site/success-stories',`

Comment: `'success-stories/<slug:\w+>' =>  'site/success-stories'` tried it but its still the same it still produce this `success-stories?slug=slug_value` and if i try to type it like this in my browser `success-stories/slug/slug_value` i get a 404 error

Comment: Can you share `urlManager` config?

Comment: But i need rules ;) Update your question with full config ;)

Comment: oh sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your rules to:

```
'rules' => [
    // page routes
    'success-stories/<slug:\w+>' => 'site/success-stories',

        // Default routes
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>', 

    // Remove 'site' parameter from URL
    '<action:(.*)>' => 'site/<action>',
],
```

Order of rules is important, Yii2 will try to match rule one by one, if it fits - it will use it.

Comment: `'success-stories/<slug>'` - how about this? Maybe your slugs contains inappropriate characters.

Comment: Great! `'success-stories/<slug>' =>  'site/success-stories'` works. but my question is this . My slug value is like `this-value` maybe that's the reason `<slug:\w+>` is not working?

Comment: `this-value` contains `-` sign, by `\w+` you allow only "word characters"

Comment: Thanks you're a great help :)